# Q: Avoid SharePoint 2016 search to match URL

Tags: search, query, crawl

Is there any way to not match users' keywords to pages' URL?

If users try to search using domain name, the whole site will be returned in result.

Example:

(Content of http://abc-sharepoint/text.txt)

```
I like to share.
```

**Current Result:**

> Search Keywords: **share**
>
> Search Results: 4 items found
>
> http://abc-sharepoint/unrealted_listsordocument/...
>
> http://abc-sharepoint/News.aspx
>
> http://differentSite/share.aspx
>
> http://abc-sharepoint/text.txt

**Expected Result:**

> Search Results:1 item found
>
> http://abc-sharepoint/text.txt

Is there anyway to configure the crawler or search web part such that SharePoint won't match users' keyword to any URLs but instead, match the pages' title / content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but theoretically it could work: `-Site:{SearchBoxQuery}` or `-Path:{SearchBoxQuery}` to filter out whole URL and not just the site part.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't it filter the contents / files that actually contains the {SearchBoxQuery} values as well? I'm gonna test it further.

Comment: Sorry, meant "Site:".

Comment: Your suggestion partially achieved the result. "-Site:{SearchBoxQuery}" filter out any result under that site. However, what I wanted to achieve is to not use any link of the URLs for keyword matching. Your suggestion do point me to the right direction. I'm trying to mess around with Manage Result Sources now. Many Thanks.

Comment: In that case, the -Path is correct, it will filter out it if the URL of the file contains the SearchBoxQuery, but will not filter out if the file contains that string.

Comment: It works, I'm sorry that I have confuse you at first. Many Thanks.